# How to determine if my AWS Glue Custom CSV Classifier is working?

Tags: amazon-web-services, csv, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I am using AWS Glue to catalog (and hopefully eventually transform) data. I am trying to create a Custom CSV Classifier for the crawler so that I can provide a known set of column headers to the table. The data is in TSV (tab separated value) format, and the files themselves have no header row. There is no 'quote' character in the data, but there are 1 or 2 columns which use a double quote in the data, so I've indicated in the Classifier that it should use single quote (`'`). To ensure I start clean, I delete the AWS Glue Catalog Table, and then run the Crawler with the Classifier attached. When I subsequently check the created table, it lists `csv` as the `classification`, and the columns names specified in the Classifier are not associated with the table (and instead are labelled as `col0`, `col1`, `col2`, `col3` etc.). Further, when inspecting a few rows in the table, it appears as though the data associated with the columns does not use the same column ordering as in the raw data itself, which I can confirm because I have a copy of the raw data open locally on my computer.

AWS Glue Classifier documentation indicates that a crawler will attempt to use the Custom Classifiers associated with a Crawler in the order they are specified in the Crawler definition, and if no match is found with certainty `1.0`, it will use Built-in Classifiers. In the event a match with certainty `1.0` is still not found, the Classifier with the highest certainty will be used.

My questions are these:

- How do I determine if my Custom CSV Classifier (which I have specifically named, say for sake of argument `customClassifier`) is actually being used, or if it is defaulting to the Built-In CSV Classifier?
- More importantly, given the situation above (having the columns known but separate from the data, and having double quotes be used in the actual data but no quoted values), how do I get the Crawler to use the specified column names for the table schema?
- Why does it appear as though my data in the Catalog is not using the column order specified in the file (even if it is the generic column names)?
- If it is even possible, how could I use an `ApplyMapping` transform to rename the columns for the workflow (which would be sufficient for my cases).? I need to do so without enabling script-only mode (by modifying an AWS Glue Studio Workflow), and without manually entering in over 200 columns

Comment: Are you using the crawler for doing anything like partitioning the source data? If you are using it simply for schema, you may want to skip the complexity of the crawler and read your files directly with a from_options read. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame-reader.html#aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame-reader-from_options take a look at the format_options parameter within that to specify the look of your data. From there you can change the column names with a line like frame = frame.toDF(["new1,"new2"],frame)

Comment: @jonlegend The primary issue with this approach is that (as I understand it) it requires you to write the code manually. While I am perfectly capable of doing this, I am using Glue to help a client build an ETL system, and would heavily prefer not to require them to learn any coding for this as they are primarily a non-software (development) based business and do not have many resources to build new pipelines by coding them. In short, I want to be able to do this via the AWS Console, not code.